# how to hide parameter value in the url using mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to protect the page by hiding the paramter value. is there anyway how to solve this?

here is my example link             http://localhost:9714/Blog/Graduate/8

Comment: What do you want to protect? Are you sending data to the server to be saved? If so, then use a `form` and post the data. If you're just accessing a specific page (to get data to the browser) I see no reason to "protect" a parameter value...

Comment: The `{id}` route param is *part of the URI*. You cannot remove it, because then it's no longer the same resource. However, an object id is not sensitive information and doesn't need to be protected. It only has meaning in the context of a database table, and if a malicious user can view your database table, then you have far more pressing issues.

Comment: I agree with @ChrisPratt but if you just don't want to _expose_ the id `8` then you could set up a new route which accepts something like `/blog/graduate` and uses `graduate` as a lookup to match to article `8`. In this case you would obviously have to set up some kind of url 'slug' field in your db which would have to be unique (so no other article could use `/graduate`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent users from trying to guess the id of a Graduate they are not allowed to access (even though you should check if the current user has access to it), you could change the `id` from `int` to `guid` (uniqueidentifier in MS SQL).

This way the url will become something like this: http://localhost:9714/Blog/Graduate/644e1dd7-2a7f-18fb-b8ed-ed78c3f92c2b

```
public class BlogController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Graduate(Guid id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: then if i do that sir i can't pass the value to the other controller sir?.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. My answer just gives the suggestion to change the parameter of the route with another unique value from what your are going to select from the database.